# html input form write to csv

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am trying to write html form data into .csv file using javascript. This is a local file so I can't use php. I am new to javascript.

html:

```
<form action="" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input type="text" name="id">
<input type="text" name="name">
<button class="submit-btn" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

js:

```
var data = [
   ['Product01', 'id-number-here']
];

function write_csv() {
    var csv = 'Product,ID\n';
    data.forEach(function(row) {
            csv += row.join(',');
            csv += "\n";
    });
}
```

How do I save the csv file in specific location on computer and then add more inputs to the csv file? User will be able to add one product at time.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot write to the local filesystem with Javascript (from a browser) as this would a security risk (imagine if every page you visit with your browser could write to your filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store the .csv file on the user's machine, the only thing you can do is make it downloadable and if his browser settings are set appropriately, he can choose the path for the file. However, you cannot access this file afterwards.
It sounds like you need to have some sort of local file retention, so why not save it in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)? You can save and retrieve the data from there with Javascript at your will.

Comment: I need to store produced product list. The way you suggest, it would make a lot of files per day.

Thanks anyways!

Comment: I could use localstorage, but there could be 20+ products and at the end of the day I need a csv file. I am not sure if storing 20+ products would be a good idea. Never have worked with localstorage so maybe this could be the way to go.

Comment: If you wanted to use a csv file in the first place, localStorage should be suitable, otherwise you would need a full-fledged database. If you are not going to be storing gigabytes of product data, it should be alright :)